# is it possible to get a bad IP address when setting up a new VPS?

Tags: vps

I'm looking to run a mail server and will be setting up a new VPS for it.  One of [the recommendations](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/issues/1880) for ensuring the deliverability of mail sent from this server is running on a "good" IP.  I'm considering Digital Ocean as a VPS provider.  With a company like that is it possible to get a "bad" IP?

A [community thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-the-ip-unique-for-each-droplet) says that IP addresses get reused.  So that means that if an IP was previously used for sending spam and then was shutdown, that would be a very bad IP address to get if they truly do get "reused" and there's no clean-slate refreshing (remove it from all blacklists) process.  Is there any kind of process like this?

When you get a new VPS, can you assume it comes with a good IP, or should you first (before installing any software/services on it) research the IP address to ensure it's not already blacklisted somewhere?

Comment: You definitely should not assume an IP is good.  There is a decent chance it is dirty; the probability depends on provider.  With some providers, the working assumption should be that it is dirty.

Comment: How would you know the IP is "good" if you _didn't_ check?